# Is there an easy way to add a secure file upload form (username, password, select file) to a website?

Tags: ftp, uploading, file-upload

I am very new to website design. Have an architect who wants his clients to enable his clients to upload (ftp - but don't know if http could be a better alternative?) files (plans etc.) to him, through the website I'm designing for him.

I have seen similar things available on printers websites...

I have seen uploadify, but it requires flash (I can only code HTML, CSS and a tiny bit of PHP), and don't think it is a secure option. I have also seen net2ftp, but don't really understand how it works.

Any direction would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would WEBDAV fit the bill at all?

Comment: Hi Jason,

Thanks for your response.

I think I tracked down the script to which you were referring here:
http://noeld.com/programs.asp?cat=misc#upload - but, it all seems a little over my head. It does sound like it does what I'm looking for, however. But may be just too advanced for my current level of skill.

I am looking at a jQuery Multiple File Upload plugin which might fit the bill - however, not sure about the security bit yet. jQuery offers a tutorial about it, too: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_File_Upload_Magic#The_Demos - and maybe this will help me, too. 

Tha